# Calculate covariance of 2 random variables when only given variance and cov

Tags: expected-value, variance, covariance

So I've been given the following exercise:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables.

Let $Var(X) = 2$ and $Cov(X, Y) = 1$. Compute $Cov(5X, 2X + 3Y)$.

How do I do this when I don't have the second variance and no expectation values?

Comment: Are you familiar with some of the basic identities related to Covariance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Covariance_of_linear_combinations? You can decompose your problem into a set of simpler problems involving covariance and variance.

Comment: Yes I know them kinda, but the problem is I only have info about one of the random variables. So I cant use that to get the other one.

Comment: You have enough information to answer the question. Why not just go back to definitions?